# Jenkins login error

Tags: jenkins, authentication

I made an administrative account and tried to login. Is there anyway to rest this issue ? [image]

Answer (score 0):

Just change the "useSecurity" element to false in the **/var/lib/jenkins/config.xml** file. This way you will be able to login and reset the password if needed.

```
<useSecurity>false</useSecurity>
```

Answer (score 0):

First make change in `jenkins/config.xml` file. 
set `useSecurity` to `false`

Then repair the Jenkins setup file.
It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Mac. In the file /Users/"yourcurrentuser"/.jenkins/config.xml, I changed the line

```
    <useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
```

into

```
    <useSecurity>false</useSecurity>
```

Then it worked without any login information